# NetCore 2.2 Change SQLConnection using environment variable

Tags: sql, controller, connection-string, asp.net-core-webapi

Need assistance with dynamically changing the connectionstring supplied in an API for netcore 2.2.

This is my sample code

Public StartUp

_connectionString = cryptography.GetProtectedValue("RandomName", dbEnvironmentVariableName);

Public ConfigureServices

services.AddDbContextPool(s => s.UseSqlServer(_connectionString));

The user can change the Environment Variable at anytime and I need to have the API pick up this change dynamically each time it is changed.

I can't find anywhere to see that this is occurring except setting up something in the controller, but that just seems wrong.

Any thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first, you need to stop using connection pooling. This allows multiple instances of your context to use the same connection, which is not something you want if that connection needs to change on the fly.

Then, you need to get the connection string *inside* the `DbContext` registration, so that each time an instance is created, it gets the connection string anew. As you have it now, it's global.

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>((provider, options) =>
{
    // get connection string
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
});
```

I'm not sure how to write this code for you as it's not clear what's going on with `cryptography.GetProtectedValue("RandomName", dbEnvironmentVariableName)`. In general, here, `provider` is going to be an instance of `IServiceProvider`, and you want to use that to get the various services you need to make this call happen.

Comment: Cryptography just returns an unencrypted connection string.  Ok on the connection pool, that makes sense.  

On the other part, I don't think this still accomplishes changing the connection while the API is up and running.  When a new instance is created then I agree, but when the API is already started it would not reset the connectionstring using this method.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: The context is request-scoped, so each request will get it's own instance, with the current connection string at that time. You are correct that once the instance is created, the connection string value is locked, and that is the case regardless. Config reload itself only happens on a per-request basis, so that's not actually an issue in practice. However, if you intend to change the connection string mid-request, then you are in fact out of luck.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was figuring, just wanted to make sure.